# How to save flutter TimeOfDay to firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, dart-pub

I am working on a flutter application where I am showing a TimeRangepicker using this plugin: [time_range_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/time_range_picker) and I am getting **TimeOfDay(09:00) + TimeOfDay(12:00)** as a result by using this code:

```
  onPressed: () async {
                        TimeRange result = await showTimeRangePicker(
                            use24HourFormat: false,
                            interval: Duration(minutes: 30),
                            context: context,
                            start: TimeOfDay(hour: 9, minute: 0),
                            end: TimeOfDay(hour: 12, minute: 0),
                            disabledTime: TimeRange(
                                startTime: TimeOfDay(hour: 23, minute: 0),
                                endTime: TimeOfDay(hour: 5, minute: 0)),
                            disabledColor: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.5),
                            strokeWidth: 4,
                            ticks: 24,
                            ticksOffset: -7,
                            ticksLength: 15,
                            ticksColor: Colors.grey,
                            labels: [
                              "12 pm",
                              "3 am",
                              "6 am",
                              "9 am",
                              "12 am",
                              "3 pm",
                              "6 pm",
                              "9 pm"
                            ].asMap().entries.map((e) {
                              return ClockLabel.fromIndex(
                                  idx: e.key, length: 8, text: e.value);
                            }).toList(),
                            labelOffset: 35,
                            rotateLabels: false,
                            padding: 60);

                        print("${result.startTime} + ${result.endTime}");
                      },
```

But the only problem is I can find an appropriate way to save this to firebase, I don't need **date** all I need is TimeOfDay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no specific data type in Firestore for storing a time of day, so you'll have to map it to one of the existing types.

Some common mapping are:

- Store the time of day as a string value, such as "07:55:00.000" (if you care up to millisecond precision)
- Store the time of day as an offset from midnight, such as 28500 (as the number of seconds from midnight until 7:55 AM)
- Store the time of day as a the time part of a fixed day in a `Timestamp` field. This is essentially a variant of the previous approach, with the offset being from the [start of the epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). Say that you pick the start of the epoch (January 1, 1970) as the fixed day, then the Timestamp's value would be 28500000 (in milliseconds).

All of these have valid use-case, so pick whichever one works best for the use-cases of your app.

Comment: Thank you so much Frank for your valuable answer, I decided to go for the 3rd suggestion on your app , I converted the timeOfDay to a timestamp on a fixed date and stored in to firestore as a timeStamp value, I then retrived the timeStamp from firestore and converted it back to TimeOfDay. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this

```
class ClassModel {
  TimeOfDay time;
  ClassModel({
    required this.time,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'time': (time.hour.toString() + "*" + time.minute.toString()),
    };
  }

  factory ClassModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return ClassModel(
      time: TimeOfDay(
          hour: int.parse(map['time'].toString().split("*").first),
          minute: int.parse(map['time'].toString().split("*").last)),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the common use case whereby only the hour and minute are required a simple map of these values will suffice.

```
Map timeOfDayToFirebase(TimeOfDay timeOfDay){
    return {
        'hour':timeOfDay.hour,
        'minute':timeOfDay.minute
           }
}


TimeOfDay firebaseToTimeOfDay(Map data){
        return TimeOfDay(
            hour: data['hour'],
            minute: data['minute']);
}



var myTimeOfDayObject=TimeOfDay.now();
firebase.update({'time': timeOfDayToFirebase(myTimeOfDayObject)});
```

This way you don't have to worry about managing offsets, unintended locale changes and so forth.